# python scipy integrate - changing parameter that is dependent on state space

Tags: python, scipy, ode

I am working on a project that requires finding the trajectory of a system of ODEs with 6 state variables. The issue is that some of the parameters depend on the state space. The system itself isn't important, but if you're interested, it is Figure 2.1 in [Adams et al 2004](https://www.ncsu.edu/crsc/reports/ftp/pdf/crsc-tr04-18.pdf). I understand how to vary parameters by time but I am unsure about how to make it a function of the state space itself

Here is an example of what I am looking for (a is a function of time)

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(1, 10,  0.5)
X0 = [0.1]
def func(X,t)
    a = 0.5 * t
    return [a * b * X[0]**2]

X, infodict = integrate.odeint(func, X0, t, full_output=True, mxstep=5000000)
```

How do I make the parameter b a function of the state space, such as b = 1/X[0]?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  Why not just implement the function in `func()`?   That is, add the line `b = 1/X[0]` (or whatever expression you need to compute the "parameters"), and then use `b` in your formula.

Comment: I guess I am not entirely sure how integrate works. Each time func is called, is X an array of the current values of the state space? If so, I can do what you said.

Comment: Yes, that is how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Using the help from the comments, I just implemented the parameter as a function of the state space. Here it is below:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np

t = np.linspace(1, 10,  0.5)
X0 = [0.1]
def func(X,t)
    a = 0.5 * t
    b = 1/X[0]
    return [a * b * X[0]**2]

X, infodict = integrate.odeint(func, X0, t, full_output=True, mxstep=5000000)
```